# Expect a timeout in Jest to be rejected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, jestjs

I have a mongodb connection and I want to test try catch when database is down. So it tries to connect to database and when it fails a Error is thorwn. But it's not working in jest. I want to get a timeout so the error is trhown, but jest just shows a timeout error

```
it('should not be able to create a new class if database is down', async () => {
    await fakeMongodb.closeDatabase();
    await expect(
      createLesson.execute({
        name: 'Lesson Test',
        description: 'Description Test',
        video: 'testurlvideo.com',
        data_init: 20210321,
        data_end: 20211031,
      }),
    ).rejects.toBeInstanceOf(AppError);
    await fakeMongodb.connect();
  });
```

How can I get it rejected after the timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're looking at is most likely due to the difference in timeout for async test in `jest`, and timeout for `mongodb.connect`

By default, timeout for any async test in jest is 5000ms. While for most mongodb driver, it is up to 30000ms by default (Please check documentation of driver you're using)

I will make an assumption that you're doing a unit test, which means the fakeMongodb is probably a `mock` version of the actual mongodb client. So you should probably share how you're doing the mock, or just purely using automock.

In case you're testing by actually connecting to the DB, you can adjust the timeout of jest test to match that of the driver you're using.

`--testTimeout= 30000// timeout of 30s`
This will be applicable for all test cases.

To only give timeout to a particular function, then you can use this syntax while declaring the test case.

`test(name, fn, timeout)`

example

```
test('example', async () => {
  

}, 10000); // timeout of 10s (default is 5000)
```

Comment: Setting the timeout for a particular function worked fine. It is taking about 11 seconds to throw the error, so I defined the timeout to 15 seconds. Thanks

Comment: Glad to be of help, let me know if you need any further help.